# How to extract only contours that look like handwritting?

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to **extract only those contours that belong to the handwriting** on this image:

[image]

Here is a code to extract the contours:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread(PATH TO FRAME)
print("img shape=", img.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("image", gray)
cv2.waitKey(1)
#### extract all contours
# Find Canny edges 
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
# Finding Contours 
# Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy() 
# since findContours alters the image 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged,  
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
  
cv2.imshow('Canny Edges After Contouring', edged) 
cv2.waitKey(0) 
  
print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours))) 
  
# Draw all contours 
# -1 signifies drawing all contours 
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3) 
  
cv2.imshow('Contours', img) 
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Comment: You could start with some neural-network model that already detects handwritten text. Then, re-train it so that it detects handwritten text and ignores machine-printed text. You could e.g. start with this word detector model: https://github.com/githubharald/WordDetectorNN

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this image specifically or for a generic image (of which this happens to be one example) - do you have the image before the working was written?

If for this image you could determine where the handwriting could be (large left hand lower rectangle) and then extract only those contours that are in that area.
You could determine this rectangle by processing the image before any writing and after, or by knowing that the area bottom left had the working on it.

Another option: You could subtract the the before image from the after to only leave what has been added.

I realise that whilst they don't actually detect handwriting from the contours, these may achieve the same goal - the more copperplate the handwriting the harder it would be to detect.  Pre-processing or obtaining the Region of Interest beforehand may make the contour problem much simpler.